# Iterate through a column and summarize findings

Tags: mysql

I have a table (t1) in mySQL that generates the following table:

```
type    time    full
0       11      yes
1       22      yes
0       11      no
3       13      no
```

I would like to create a second table (t2) from this that will summarize the information found in t1 like the following:

```
type    time    num_full   total
0       11      1          2
1       22      1          1
3       13      0          1
```

I want to be able to iterate through the type column in order to be able to start this summary, something like a for-loop. The types can be up to a value of n, so I would rather not write n+1 `WHERE` statements, then have to update the code every time more types are added.

Notice how t2 skipped the type of value 2? This has also been escaping me when I try looping. I only want the the types found to have rows created in t2.

While a direct answer would be nice, it would be much more helpful to be pointed to some sources where I could figure this out, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do what you want

```
create table t2 if not exists select type, time, sum(full) num_full, count(*) count
from t1 
group by type,time
order by type,time;
```

depending on how you want to aggregate the time column.

This is a starting point for reference on the group by functions : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html
here for create syntax
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Comment: NOTE if the 'full' column is not bool (TinyInt) then you can use a case statement inside the SUM function eg if 'full' is string 'yes'/'no' values then you could use SUM( CASE WHEN full='yes' THEN  ELSE 0 END)

Comment: SUM( CASE WHEN full='yes' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)